# How to ignore libraries in browserify programmatic api

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, browserify

Assume the below code is found in `bundler.js` and tracing `entry.js` leads to `var B = require('backbone');` (Backbone is a dependency installed as declared in `package.json`).

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var bundle = new browserify();
bundle.add('entry.js');
bundle.bundle({
  noParse: ['backbone']
});
```

Executing this bundler yields a stream that contains the original `backbone` source.  Based on browserify's [command line options](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/wiki#usage) I expected it to skip backbone alltogether. Reading through the source, I expected perhaps the following would work:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var bundle = new browserify({
    noParse: ['backbone']
});
bundle.add('entry.js');
bundle.bundle();
```

Though `backbone` source still appears in the stream output.

Is it possible to use `--noparse=FILE` as a configuration option in this application of the api?

Answer (score 11):

As you can see [from here](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/b24fbc3d8d9ba775d9b70a31d0b5d21be084a9e7/bin/args.js#L36-L39) the `--noparse` option provided on the command line is passed to the `browserify({ })` call.

So in order to tell browserify to not parse jquery and three.js you have to pass the full path to your jquery and three.js files.

Example:

```
browserify({
  noParse: [
   require.resolve('./vendor/jquery'),
   require.resolve('./vendor/three')
  ]
})
.require(require.resolve('./entry.js'), { entry: true })
.bundle();
```

Comment: I appreciate the reference to source. I implemented a similar block but the parse times with and without noParse on all large files (jQuery, Backbone, Lodash) is identical: ~15seconds. to me, that suggests the files are indeed still being parsed

Comment: I had trouble verifying noParse actually worked. I ended up adding `console.log(file);` in `node_modules/browserify/index.js`' `globalTr` function just before the `var parts = file.split('/node_modules/');` line. It helped me realize I was using the wrong paths for the file I wanted to ignore.
I wish browserify had a more verbose `--verbose` mode.

Answer (score 9):

```
var browserify = require("browserify")

browserify({entries: ['./src/client/app.js']})
.ignore('jquery')
```

That would make browserify ignore jquery, and then jquery can be added on index.html directly.

Comment: Perhaps a little more explanation?

Comment: this worked for me, thanks, example: 
browserify({entries: ['./js/index.js']}).ignore('backbone').ignore('jquery').ignore('underscore')

Comment: More example of chart.js that did it here https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L105